# how to enter multiple spaces in .md (markdown) file so that the converted html shows same amout of spaces?

Tags: html, markdown

I've seen a couple of quetion/answers in SO but couldn't understand any of it because they all didn't explain how I can inserted the "&nbsp;" characters, etc.  I'm editing an .md file in which I want to insert some spaces to show directory structure. By the way, those lines are wrapped by ``` lines at the top and bottom but when converted to html by markdown, the spaces are just collapsed. This is the sample code(? it's not code actually).

### directoies

```
            ----qemu-5.1.0
            ----qemu_test
                        ----test_app
                        |          ----include
                        ----test_ldd
                        |          ----linux-5.4.0
                        ----test_ubuntu
```

When converted into html, it looks like this.

## directoies

```
----qemu-5.1.0
----qemu_test
----test_app
| ----include
----test_ldd
| ----linux-5.4.0
----test_ubuntu
```

How should I do it??  (I'm doing it on ubuntu 20.04 using vnc on windows 10 machine)

Comment: How are you converting it into html? and have you tried using tabs instead?

Comment: You are doing it correctly, just copy/pasted the code on https://markdownlivepreview.com/ and I'm getting the folders with a correct indent. Does the HTML use a particular stylesheet? See if there's a change in <pre> and <code> tags.

Comment: @DevWithZachary I tried tab, it doesn't work.

Comment: @ChanKim what are you using to create the html? You are doing the right thing in markdown, but perhaps the translator you are using has special requirements

Comment: @Salketer but the example code doesn't have multiple space characters example.

Comment: @DevWithZachary sorry I'm doing markdown aa.md > aa.html.